# Set of derivatives of a normal family of analytic functions is itself a normal family.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a problem that is easily solvable if I can prove the statement in the title. Here's what I've done so far:

Given $\mathscr{F}$ a normal family of analytic functions, let $\mathscr{F}'=\{f':f\in \mathscr{F}\}$. Let $\{f_n'\}$ be a sequence in $\mathscr{F}'$. Then the corresponding sequence $\{f_n\}$ (unique up to constants) contains a subsequence that converges to some analytic $f$. This implies that the subsequence of derivatives converges to $f'$, so every sequence in $\mathscr{F}'$ has a subsequence that converges and $\mathscr{F}'$ is normal.

Am I missing something here? It seems like a very strong statement that I wouldn't necessarily expect to be true, but I can't think of a counterexample either.

Comment: One could say that you should state the type of convergence (locally uniform, or, if you prefer, compact), but other than that, nothing to object. The Cauchy integral makes it easy to see that locally uniform convergence of a sequence of holomorphic functions implies locally uniform convergence of the sequence of derivatives of arbitrary order.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I meant uniform convergence on compact subsets, which also implies the same convergence of a sequence of derivatives fairly easily.

Comment: Yes, since the domain is locally compact, uniform convergence on compact subsets (aka compact convergence) is the same as locally uniform convergence. That's the adequate convergence for holomorphic functions in most settings, so unless something else is explicitly stated, it's tacitly assumed most of the time. My point was that it may be preferable to explicitly say that you're speaking of locally uniform (= compact) convergence.